# error at compiling : 'class TwoWire' has no member named 'setClock'

Tags: i2c, raspberrypi, compilation-errors

I am a newbie C programmer and I just started with Arduino **web editor** (Win10-Firefox)to code for a **Raspberry Pi** (3B) board. RPi is on line via ethernet connection.

I tried to compile an example from Garmin Lidar_lite v3HP for I2C, as available in the library collections for Arduino.
When compiling the example I get after a while this error message:

*Using library Wire in folder: /home/builder/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/mraa/1.0.8/libraries/Wire (legacy)*

*Using library lidar_lite_3_0_3 at version 3.0.3 in folder: /home/builder/opt/libraries/latest/lidar_lite_3_0_3*

*/tmp/967842743/v3HP_I2C/v3HP_I2C.ino: In function 'void setup()':*

*/tmp/967842743/v3HP_I2C/v3HP_I2C.ino:51:18: error: 'class TwoWire' has no member named 'setClock'*

*Wire.setClock(400000UL); // Set I2C frequency to 400kHz (for Arduino Due)*

^
*exit status 1*

Checking the arduino forum I find some similar question, but of many years ago and likely not applicable any longer.

I appreciate your expert inputs on how to resolve in simple terms.
Thanks a lot! Greetz, Ivan

Comment: You're trying to compile code to run on a Pi? What core did you install into the IDE to do that?

Comment: Yes, that is the intent. Arduino web editor offers possibility to select not only arduino boards, but also linux based ARM systems such as RPi  board and also other SBC are supported by the web editor. I have seen Youtube tutorial that was demonstrating web editor en RPi.- see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVS9zIcWa7w . That triggerd my interest.

Comment: Then probably the library in that (unknown?) core doesn't support that functionality. Maybe that functionality doesn't make any sense on a Linux computer where I guess the clock speed may be set in the DT overlay.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried again with the arduino on PC with RasPiDuino librarie and had no further problem. The resulting executable does work on a RPi3 wirh Buster OS. Apparently the arduino webeditor lacks some libraries to succesfully compile for raspberry  . I continue this road. Item can be closed.

Comment: You should write that as an answer then wait the prescribe period (if there is one) and accept your own answer. That way people looking for an answer to the same problem can easily find it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply. I tried again with the arduino on PC with RasPiDuino librarie and had no further problem. The resulting executable does work on a RPi3 with Buster OS. Apparently the arduino webeditor lacks some libraries to succesfully compile for raspberry . I continue this road. Item can be closed.

Comment: If you now wish to delete your question, just use the 'delete' button on the question.